# How to solve the following two problems of linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression

[image]

I have been confused by the problem (9.3). I think it's reasonable when adding more predictors in the regression, the SSE would be less. Yet, I don't know how to proof it.
Besides, problem 10.1 seems to imply the (9.3) is an chi-square random variable. But I still have no idea about how to prove it.
Please give me some hint, and thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to the site! How much do you know about these mathematical objects that have the form $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{A}^\top\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{A}^\top$, that go by names like "Projection operator", "Projector", "Hat Matrix" or "Projection Matrix"?

Comment: Another way to state (9.3) is "when you add more explanatory variables in a (least squares) minimization problem, the optimal value cannot increase."

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a) It is pretty clearly a self study question b) The author has not responded to comments and c) He has not, in fact, been on the site since April.